# How to display file properties dialog security tab from c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

This post: [How do I display a file's Properties dialog from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936682/how-do-i-display-a-files-properties-dialog-from-c) describes how to display file's Properties dialog from, I was wondering if it's possible to use same method but set opened tab to securety? From C# code.

See image below.

[image: Folder Properties Security Tab]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one invoke the Windows Permissions dialog programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035464/how-does-one-invoke-the-windows-permissions-dialog-programmatically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `info.lpParameters = "Security";` to show Security tab.

Or `info.lpParameters = "Details";` to show Details tab.

Now ShowFileProperties method is:

```
    public static bool ShowFileProperties(string Filename)
    {
        SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
        info.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        info.lpVerb = "properties";
        info.lpFile = Filename;
        info.lpParameters = "Security";
        info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
        info.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
        return ShellExecuteEx(ref info);
    }
```

Reference: [To show the properties page of a file and navigate to a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213903/to-show-the-properties-page-of-a-file-and-navigate-to-a-tab)